# A Problem with changing width of a gridview column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a datatable binded with gridview and I want to change the column width.
This it the code I use:

```
DataTable aTable = new DataTable("Words"); 
aTable.Columns.Add("word");

GridView1.DataSource = aTable;
DataRow a = aTable.NewRow();
a[0] = "test";
aTable.Rows.Add(a);
GridView1.DataBind();

GridView1.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
```

When the execution gets to the last line it produces an error saying that the column with index 0 is not found, howerver it is in the datatable and it is shown in the webpage.

Why doesn't the gridview see the column and is there a way around this?

Comment: Where are you placing this code?

Comment: The error's there whereever I put it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column count will always be 0 unless you explicitly define `<columns>` in your gridview.

You are autogenerating. So use `<columns>` with  `<asp:BoundField DataField="word" />`and it will work.

Comment: When I do that and bind it with my datatable it displays 2 equal columns. It doesn't merge the columns into one, it clones them. How can I fix that?

Comment: the markup is thus

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="word" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

works a treat

Comment: I didn't have this attribute - AutoGenerateColumns="False". I have not thought of that. Silly me. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try placing this in the grid view's prerender event.  You may be trying to do this in the wrong spot.

**EDIT** Try adding this before your statement:

```
if(GridView1.Columns.Count > 0)
//do stuff here
```

Comment: The error still remains if put in the GridView1_PreRender function.

Comment: GridView1.Columns.Count is in fact 0. This is the actual problem. The question is why is that so and how can I fix it.